# Распарсить текстовые файлы в словарь словарей на Python

Tags: python-3.x

Есть папка с папками, в которых лежат текстовые файлы с информацией о раздачах рутрекера, такого вида:

```
"321";"Отчеты о встречах";"610384";"7A6AD2DB00CBC22F29A19E1CBF943CE23CA0C234";"Новогодняя торрентовка 22.12.2007 (Слайд-шоу) DVDRip";"148795392"
"321";"Отчеты о встречах";"3001713";"F72185F392D507228F6D3B3976FABEE9BACEEBA0";"Минифотоотчет о торрентовке в Киеве 6.06.2010";"102918123"
"321";"Отчеты о встречах";"3002098";"445374A0CBEE6DBDCD56DD0689E20F728C0F9B3E";"Киевская Торрентовка [2010.06.06]";"64412253"
...
```

Таких тестовых файлов очень много, на 5 гб. Я пытаюсь реализовать функцию поиска по ним (поиск не линейны), для этого хочу разложить все загрузки с учетом категорий и подкатегорий в словарь словарей, чтобы при поиске указывать категорию и подкатегорию, отсекая ненужные разделы.

До этого я получил словарь следующего вида:

```
service_cat = 
{
  "Обсуждения, встречи, общение": [
    "category_1.csv"
  ],
  "Кино, Видео и ТВ": [
    "category_2.csv",
    "category_3.csv"
  ],
  "Новости": [
    "category_4.csv",
    "category_5.csv",
    "category_6.csv",
    "category_7.csv"
  ],
  "Музыка": [
    "category_8.csv"
  ],
  "Программы и Дизайн": [
    "category_9.csv"
  ],
...
}
```

В словаре для каждой категории указаны файлы, в которых эта категория лежит. Это справедливо для всех папок.

Итерируясь по этому словарю и по файлам хочется собрать собрать словарей вида:

```
    { Категория_1: {
        Подкатегория_1: {
            Имя_Раздачи_1: [имя_раздачи, магнет-ссылка, размер файла],
            Имя_Раздачи_2: [имя_раздачи, магнет-ссылка, размер файла],
            Имя_Раздачи_3: [имя_раздачи, магнет-ссылка, размер файла],
            Имя_Раздачи_4: [имя_раздачи, магнет-ссылка, размер файла]
            }
        Подкатегория_2: {
            Имя_Раздачи_1: [имя_раздачи, магнет-ссылка, размер файла],
            Имя_Раздачи_2: [имя_раздачи, магнет-ссылка, размер файла],
            ...
            }
        ...
        }
    ...    
}
```

На мой взгляд подобная структура данных позволит сократить время поиска. Но собрать её у меня не получается.

Для этого я попытался написать функцию, которая итерируется по файлам, словарю service_cat и по данным из них собирает требуемый словарь словарей.

```
def find_categories(service_cat):
    """
    Функция, которая считывает категории из файлов архива и записывает их в служебный файл.
    :return: словарь с категориями
    """

    global categories_dict
    # Обходим папку с папками и собираем дерево
    tree = os.walk(torrent_archive)
    # Итерируемся по файлам в дереве
    for root, dirs, files in tree:
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                # итерируемя по словарю service_cat
                for key, value in service_cat.items():
                    if str(file) in value:
                        file_path = str(root) + '\\' + str(file)
                        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
                            torrents_in_forum = []
                            for line in csv_file:
                                torrent_info = {}
                                # print(key, line)
                                forum_id = line.split(';')[0].replace('"', '')
                                forum_name = line.split(';')[1].replace('"', '')
                                distribution_id = line.split(';')[2].replace('"', '')
                                distribution_hash = line.split(';')[3].replace('"', '')
                                torrent_name = line.split(';')[4].replace('"', '')
                                size_in_bytes = line.split(';')[5].replace('"', '').replace('\n', '')
                                magnet_link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:' + distribution_hash
                                # Если печатаю данные из строчек - то все работает
                                # print(key, forum_name, torrent_name, magnet_link)

                                # А словарь разложить не получается
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Тут было много решений, но нужного результата я не добивался. 
#То собирается нужная структура данных, но данные лежат не те. 
#То собирается структура с правильными данными, но данных явно не хватает. 
#На то, что написано ниже можно не смотреть. 
#Попробовал от безысходности отработать одну мысль, да не вышло.
                #                 link_info = [magnet_link, str(size_in_bytes) + ' ' + 'bytes']
                #                 torrent_info[torrent_name] = link_info
                #                 torrents_in_forum.append(torrent_info)
                #
                # # print(torrents_in_forum)
                # categories_dict[key][forum_name] = torrents_in_forum


                        # categories_dict[key][forum_name] = torrents_in_forum
                                # forum[forum_name] = torrents_in_forum
                                # categories_dict[key] = forum
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #Записываем словарь словарей в файл, чтобы при поиске итерироваться по его содержимому
    with open('categories.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as c:
         json.dump(categories_dict, c, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    print(categories_dict)
    return categories_dict
```

Помогите пожалуйста собрать словарь словарей. Вроде бы делаю аналогично тем примерам, которые нахожу в интернете, но что-то идет не так. И я не понимаю что.

PS: Еще у меня есть подозрение, что будет лучше так же разложить данные в SQL-базу и при поиске брать значение из неё. С данной темой я пока знаком только по паре статей и руками ничего не делал. Если у кого-то есть какие-то мысли на данный счет, буду признателен.

Comment: `Еще у меня есть подозрение, что будет лучше так же разложить данные в SQL` это даже не обсуждается: если файлы весят 5 гигов, то загруженные в память интерпретатора будут весить все 25. Первым делом стоит начать копать в сторону баз данных, которые и 20 лет назад с такими объемами справлялись шутя.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже начал пробовать. Пока не до конца понимаю, какие бывают базы и как лучше в них раскладывать. Планирую действовать следующим образом: 1) Создать в БД раздел под каждую категорию. 2) В каждую категорию разложить подкатегории. 3) В каждую подкатегорию разложить данные загрузки в виде связанных значений имя_загрузки: информация_о_загрузке.

Comment: В бд обычно таблицы, как в `excel`, например.. В вашем случае львиная доля всех данных будет храниться в единственной таблице, в таком виде как будто это все csv слиты воедино. А иерархия будет задаваться парочкой мелких табличек. Сервер бд позволяет делать очень гибкие и быстрые выборки данных, даже если данные вот так свалены в одну таблицу. Но это получается не само собой - базу данных нужно грамотно спроектировать. Рекомендую пройти какой-нибудь онлайн курс, например [Введение в базы данных](https://stepik.org/course/551)